# Interpolate error while searching x value if y = 0

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I'm taking begining course in python and I'm having some troubles identifying the x value if my y = 0. Is it even posible in the manner or is there another way?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200]
y = [0.166, 0.282, 0.032, -0.124, -0.292]

y_value = 0
print(np.interp(y_value, y, x))

plt.plot(y, x, '--ro')
plt.show()
```

I tried to use numpy.interp() but the with every y-value I enter in '200' is the output.

Comment: `y` is not monotonically decreasing, so you can't use it as the independent variable here.

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Do you have a suggestion how to obtain the x value of y = 0?

Comment: You can use some other interpolator, such as a cubic spline, and then find the root (i.e. zero-crossing) of the result.

Comment: You might end up with multiple roots if you do this.

Comment: You could just drop the non-monotonic part of the array by trimming off the first elements. It shouldn't affect much in this case at least.

Answer (score 2):

### Beginner Solution

For your purposes as a beginner, I would just do a simple linear interpolation of the values around 0. What I mean by that is find the slope and y-intercept between the x and y points around `y=0` and use that to find the approximate solution of x at `y=0`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200]
y = [0.166, 0.282, 0.032, -0.124, -0.292]

slope = (y[3] - y[2]) / (x[3] - x[2]) # Find the slope between (100,0.032) and (150,-0.124)
y_int = y[3] - (slope * x[3])         # Find y-intercept at some point (I just chose 3)

print((0 - y_int) / slope)            # y = mx + b --> x = (y - b)/m
```

I am assuming that since you are taking a beginner course, this might be a good enough solution. However, there are other ways to solve this problem!

### More Fun Solution: SciPy Interpolate

To clarify what @jared said in his comment, you can create a spline, or "best fit line," to fit the data as best you can, derive the polynomial of the function of the spline, and solve that function for `y = 0`. SciPy has some pretty cool tools for you to do this. It's not the most beginner-friendly solution in my opinion, but it is incredibly useful.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, PPoly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200]
y = [0.166, 0.282, 0.032, -0.124, -0.292]

spline = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=3) # Create a cubic spline from the data
curve  = PPoly.from_spline(spline)     # Create a piecewise polynomial object; in essence, y = curve(x)
print(curve.solve(y=0))                # Solve for y = 0
```

For creating the spline, I set `k=3` to specify a cubic spline; however, setting `k=2` or `k=4` is also valid. Setting `k=1` may not be your best bet because that will create a linear spline, and it seems that your data switches from trending positive to negative, meaning your solution for `x` at `y=0` may not be accurate.

The second line where `curve` is defined utilizes a cool class in SciPy called `PPoly`, which you can read a bit about in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.html). In essence, the spline gets converted into a piecewise function that can be solved at any `y` point.

Just make sure to install SciPy with `pip install scipy` before running this. Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also use `curve.roots()` instead of `curve.solve(y=0)`.